# Query Firestore in Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

where calues not working it does not filter results how i can fix it

here is my database [image]
[image]

here is my code

```
 CollectionReference collection = mDB.collection("full_order");
    Query query = collection.whereEqualTo("Bakeryid", "1");
    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d("Results", task.getResult().toString());
                Toasty.success(getContext(), "Succefuul ", Toasty.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                userOrder = task.getResult().toObjects(UserOrder.class);
                adapterTruckDrivers = new RecycleViewAdapterTruckDrivers(getContext(), userOrder);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterTruckDrivers);

            } else {
                Log.d("Results", "Errrror");
                //   Log.d("Results",task.getResult().toString());
                Toasty.error(getContext(), "Error ", Toasty.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

and i have a quastion
can i use FirebaseDatabase methods like child etc.. when i am using Firestore ?

Comment: add your database structure image, it'll help to figure out it.

Comment: Edited.........

Comment: you have this Tyc... thing in the middle

Comment: I dont understand ?

Comment: I cannot see any `Bakeryid` property in your document. Can you please add a more detailed screenshot? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo nvm my code worked i forget to enable firebase authentication in my app

Comment: Thank you @AlexMamo BakeryId property is in user sub document ,not shown here if you want i will post a screenshot

Comment: Yes, add to your question.

Comment: lol, i find its already in the question section its in full_order-document name-order-bakeryid @AlexMamo

Comment: I see now, I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
Query query = collection.whereEqualTo("Bakeryid", "1");
```

to

```
Query query = collection.whereEqualTo("order.BakeryID", 1);
```

There are three problems in your code.

- The name of the property is `BakeryID` and **not** `Bakeryid`. See lowercase `id`?
- That property is nested under the `order` Map. You should specify that in your query.
- You are passing to the `whereEqualTo()` **one** as a `String` and not as a `Number`. In your database, the value of that property is **not** a String. See, it does not contain quotation marks?

Answer (score 1):

i'm not familiar with firestore but you need to query document before referring to next collection, like this

```
String id  = "Tyc...."
CollectionReference collection = mDB.collection("full_order");
Query query =collection.document(id).whereEqualT..
```

To understand and learn more refer to this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

Comment: my code worked i forget to enable firebase authentication in my app

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
 CollectionReference collection = mDB.collection("full_order");
    Query query = collection.whereEqualTo("Bakeryid", "1");
```

into this:

```
 CollectionReference collection = mDB.collection("full_order");
    Query query = collection.whereEqualTo("bakeryID", "1");
```

The attribute inside `whereEqualTo` should match the one in the database

Comment: my code worked i forget to enable firebase authentication in my app